# Not authorized to use Google Cloud Datastore for this project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

As of today I'm unable to Query my own Datastore from the new App Engine Admin console. I'm stopped by an Datastore Error "You are not authorized to use Google Cloud Datastore for this project."

I'm the owner of the project and I've tried on other "owner" accounts but I get the same error. It was working fine last week.

Comment: Can you share your app id (email to eddavisson@google.com) so I can take a look?

Comment: what APIs are turned ON ?

Comment: Is your App Engine app is set to use Apps Domain auth?  I had the same issue recently and opened a support case with Google, who are investigating.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Apps Domain Auth enabled as well, this is pretty annoying...

Comment: Yes - we're a google Apps Domain and I have it set to limit real users to our domain only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (reported and fixed) few months ago, I guess it came back with the last admin console update last week.

It is not a decent workaround but if you really need to perform a query before they fixe the issue you can:

- open the datastore query page
- remove the error from the html
- select "Query using GQL" (this one is still working apparently)

Comment: Or just use the old Datastore Viewer at [appengine.google.com](https://appengine.google.com) for now. GQL is not available for EU-hosted apps on the new console.

Comment: Well, that's way better yes :)

Comment: Thanks both of you - what a pain. They really need a way to report these things with out having silver/gold/cashgrab support levels. I don't need support .... you do Google.

Comment: Hello, I'm Mario and I work at Google Cloud Support. I've sent you an email to follow up with you on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's been resolved as of Today. I'm now able to access the Datastore Query page.