# Developers Console, datastore query: No Entity Found due to space in entity name

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Recently, it seems like Google made a change to the cloud datastore viewer, such that now, I can't click on any entities that contain a space ' ' in their name, to edit them. For example, when I click on an entity 'code User' it pops up an error like this:

> No Entity Found We could not find an entity with namespace: ""
>   (Default Namespace), kind: "User", and identifier
>   "name=aziLYeJdTTF2Ojdvu-PbT5g"

However, I could still edit entities with no space, such as 'code_User'.

Looking at the URL:
https://console.developers.google.com/project/landshark-zenkoi-code/datastore/editentity/?key=%2Fcode%20User%20name%3AaziLYeJdTTF2Ojdvu-PbT5g

I deduce that spaces in our entity names, e.g. "code User" don't work with the updated google datastore viewer, because they use space to separate kind and entity IDs in the URL now. I've tried enclosing the kind name with %3F ("), but that doesn't help.

Fortunately, the workaround is to use the old website at https://appengine.google.com/. Editing of cloud datastore entities containing spaces still work here. Hopefully this won't get decommissioned anytime soon.

Will there be a bug fix to allow us to, once again, use the new datastore query page with entities that have spaces in their name?

Comment: Possibly related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354624/not-authorized-to-use-google-cloud-datastore-for-this-project) as there seem to have been some recent changes to the console.

Comment: I don't think it's related. I can still access my datastore. I just can't edit entities with spaces in the entity name. A problem I hope Google will address soon.