# Google Console - Cloud Datastore Query returning "Backend Error"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In Google Console, I get

> "Backend Error"

when trying the access Cloud Datastore administration screens (`Dashboard` & `Query` screens return "`Backend Error`". `Index` screen works, somehow).

When looking at my App Engine Logs, I see this in my default module logs:

`404 - /datastore/v1beta2/RunQuery
Error 404: The resource could not be found.`

The same code in development, and deployed to another App Engine application works perfectly.
Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the console page? They seem to have recently deployed a new version of the console so perhaps your client is out of date?  That said, there is also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354624/not-authorized-to-use-google-cloud-datastore-for-this-project).

Comment: Does it happens even in old Console at https://appengine.google.com/ ?

Comment: I have tried reloading the console page multiple times. Tried to shutdown/restart the instance, change the app versions, nothing makes any difference.

Comment: The old console at appengine.google.com works well. I can see my data in the datastore as usual.

Comment: Can you pass along your project id (email to eddavisson@google.com) so I can take a closer look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Developer Console Internal Error with Datastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463326/google-developer-console-internal-error-with-datastore)