# Google Developer Console Internal Error with Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-console-developer

I still use the legacy dev console most of the time because whenever I've tried the newer console it has always given an "Internal Error" when trying to view datastore entities or view to Queries section.

I was hoping the new, more colorful dev console would finally fix this problem but it gives the same internal error.

The only thing I don't get errors for is looking at Datastore Indexes. That seems to work fine. But Dashboard, Query, and Settings all fail to load with the same "Internal Error".

Please let me know if there's anything I can do to fix this. I'm very worried that you're going to completely decommission the legacy console and then I'll be unable to support my users.

Thanks,

Stephen

Comment: This can happen sometimes and is caused by part of the Cloud Datastore infrastructure that is going away soon. You should either file a bug on the GAE public issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry) or PM me your project ID and I can re-activate it for you.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I emailed your google address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across the issue, there are a few ways to resolve this:

1. In the APIs section of the Dev Console, disable then re-enable the Cloud Datastore API.
2. File a bug on the [GAE public issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry) (You can also send me an email directly with your Cloud project ID.)

For those interested in what is actually going on:

The Developers Console uses the Cloud Datastore API to access your project's Datastore. The current version of the Cloud Datastore API (v1beta2) uses a special version on your App Engine application (ah-builtin-datastoreservice) in order to serve this API. Unfortunately, sometimes when you first enable the Cloud Datastore API the deployment of this version fails.

We are currently working to remove this layer of the serving stack for the next version of the Cloud Datastore API.

EDIT: Cloud Console now uses Cloud Datastore API v1beta3, so disabling then re-enabling likely will not solve any connection issues.

Comment: Patrick, I cannot view my app's datastore at the new Cloud Datastore Dashboard. Perhaps I don't know where to look.  [my dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine?project=tellmestraight-hrd&moduleId=default&duration=P30D).

Comment: @zerowords Can you send me an email (pcostello@google.com) with a .har file captured when you try to connect?  As a note, this answer is no longer accurate. The Cloud Console uses the new version of the Cloud Datastore API, which shouldn't have these connection issues.